# Vue - component props not watching object changes properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have two objects in my root - `obj` and `newObj`. I watch changes on my `obj` object with `deep: true`, and on changes I update newObj accordingly.

In my vue debugger, the `newObj` seems updated as expected, however the component doesn't perform the for loop count. Or if I try to `{{ newObj }}`, it logs only the first update.

I tried to re-create the issue [on this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lp9nmxn9/).

my html:

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="appendTo">Append</button>
  <my-comp v-bind:new-obj="newObj"></my-comp>
</div>
```

and vue:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    obj: {},
    newObj: {}
  },

  methods: {
    appendTo() {
      if (typeof this.obj[1] === 'undefined') {
        this.$set(this.obj, 1, {})
      }

      var randLetter = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (122 - 97)) + 97);
         this.$set(this.obj[1], randLetter, [ [] ])
      }
    },

  watch: {
    obj: {
        handler(obj) {
        var oldKeys = Object.keys(obj)
        var newKeys = Object.keys(this.newObj);

        var removedIndex = newKeys.filter(x => oldKeys.indexOf(x) < 0 );
        for (var i = 0, len = removedIndex.length; i < len; i++) {
          delete this.newObj[removedIndex[i]]
        }

        oldKeys.map((key) => {
          if (this.newObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var newInnerKeys = Object.keys(this.newObj[key]);
            var oldInnerKeys = Object.keys(obj[key]);

            var additions = oldInnerKeys.filter(x => newInnerKeys.indexOf(x) < 0);

            for (var i = 0, len = additions.length; i < len; i++) {
              // here
              this.$set(this.newObj[key], additions[i], [ [] ]);
            }

            var deletions = newInnerKeys.filter(x => oldInnerKeys.indexOf(x) < 0);
            for (var i = 0, len = deletions.length; i < len; i++) {
              delete this.newObj[key][deletions[i]]
            }

          } else {
            this.newObj[key] = {}
            for (var innerKey in obj[key]) {
              this.$set(this.newObj, key, {
                [innerKey]: [ [] ]
              });
            }
          }

          console.log(obj);
          console.log(this.newObj)
        });
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('my-comp', {
    props: ['newObj'],
  template: `
        <div>
        <div v-for="item in newObj">
            test
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
```

Comment: can you try to update direclty `this.newObj` and not the keys inside `this.newObj`. You can cheat with `this.newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.newObject))` at the end. `deep: true` apply for obj not for newObj so if the reference is not updated, the UI is not updated

Comment: But then, how will I be able to append to existing key values? Wouldn't it just override the existing values and solely keep this item? I'd be grateful for any guidance

Comment: You can append to existing key values but you need to tell vuejs that your object has changed and it should re render. Vuejs by default, only watch the reference of newObj it means if you change this object like that: this.newObj = otherObject, it will works. I'm not sure this is your problem this is why you should test my suggestion. Or use Object.assign or other stuff to change the reference and see if the UI updates.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to exactly copy what is inside obj, I want to put different data inside newObj, but according to the changes in obj. That's why I can't use `this.newObj = otherObj`. Or am I misunderstanding your solution? I'd be grateful if you can add an answer or place it in the fiddle..

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work and throw in the console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
    at window.onload`

Comment: @Epitouille The fiddle is working man, you just need to ignore the jsfiddle error which is there by default, and just watch variable logs on console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151343/discussion-between-epitouille-and-senty).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data `newObj` has a getter and setter defined by vue. When the setter is called, the UI is re-rendered. The setter is triggered when you change the **reference** of `newObj`, not when you change its value. I mean:

```
this.newObj = {} // triggered

this.newObj['key'] = 'value' // not triggered
```

You can add a deep watcher on the property `this.newObj`. Or change its reference with a trick:

```
this.newObj = Object.assign({}, this.newObjec);
```

which create a copy of the object `newObject`.

Here is the fiddle updated.

https://jsfiddle.net/749nc5d2/

Comment: I did `var scalfold = this.newObj[key]; delete this.newObj[key]` and then `this.$set(this.newObj, key, scalfold)` - and it worked.. Do you think it is a wrong approach? (just asking out of curiosity. Your method seems so much clear and the right way. just tested it out and it works like charm)

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html Here is a very interesting link. By default, only the reference of the object is reactive. Reactive means, update the UI (and other stuff when the value change). `this.$set` add a key to an object that will be reactive. So when you create `this.newObj` the first time, you can create it with this.$set and your object will be fully reactive. The link below shows the 2 methods (this.$set and Object.assign)